# SVG's not being imported correctly with Encore, SVGR and React

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack-encore

I am working on an existing Symfony project, with a frontend built using Encore. We are refactoring part of the frontend to React and I am at the point where I want to add SVG's for icons. I cannot use an img tag with the path as the source, so I need to inline the SVG's in some way.

I tried doing this with SVGR, and I see my SVG's being turned into React components, but when I import them, the import returns the path of the file, instead of the actual component.

Encore config:

```
Encore
.setOutputPath('web/build/react')

// the public path used by the web server to access the previous directory
.setPublicPath('/build/react')
.addEntry('react', '/react/app.js')
// enable source maps during development
.enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())

// empty the outputPath dir before each build
.cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()

// show OS notifications when builds finish/fail
.enableBuildNotifications()

.enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

.enableStimulusBridge('./react/controllers.json')
.enableTypeScriptLoader()

// create hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
.enableVersioning()
.configureBabel((config)=>{
    config.presets.push('@babel/preset-react')
})
.addRule({
    test: /\.(sass|scss|svg|png|jpe?g)$/,
    use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                modules: {
                    localIdentName: "[local]-[hash:base64:8]"
                }
            }
        },
        'sass-loader'
    ]
})
.addRule({
    test: /\.svg/,
    type: "asset/resource",
    generator: {
        filename: "[path][name]-[hash][ext][query]"
    }
})

var configReact = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
configReact.target = ['browserslist'];
configReact.name = 'react';

configReact.resolve.alias = {
        "@symfony/stimulus-bridge/controllers.json": "/react/controllers.json",
        "@src": "/react/src",
}
```

Icon component:

```
import React from "react";
import { DecoratedProps } from "@src/types/componentHelpers";
import arrow from "@src/assets/icons/arrow.svg";

export interface Props {
    icon: IconType
}

export default class Icon extends React.Component<DecoratedProps<Props>> {
    constructor(props: DecoratedProps<Props>) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (<Arrow />)
    }
}
```

I get an error on `createElement` since it tries to use the file path as tag name.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it with help of this issue: https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/886.

The main problem was that Encore has some default loaders that it configures underwater, among which one that picks up all images and uses a file loader on them.

I had to reconfigure that loader to ignore SVG's. I added the next bit to my webpack.config.js:

```
Encore.configureLoaderRule("images", (loaderRule) => {
    loaderRule.test = new RegExp(loaderRule.test.toString().replace('|svg', ''));
  });
```

My Icon component now looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { DecoratedProps } from "@src/types/componentHelpers";
import Arrow from "@src/assets/icons/arrow.svg";
import Vrijwilliger from "@src/assets/icons/vrijwilliger.svg";

export enum IconType {
    Arrow = "Arrow",
    Vrijwilliger = "Vrijwilliger",
}

export interface Props {
    icon: IconType
}

export default class Icon extends React.Component<DecoratedProps<Props>> {
    constructor(props: DecoratedProps<Props>) {
        super(props);
    }

    iconLookup = {
        [IconType.Arrow]: <Arrow />,
        [IconType.Vrijwilliger]: <Vrijwilliger />
    }

    render() {
        const SVG = this.iconLookup[this.props.icon]
        return (<>{SVG}</>)
    }
}
```

This could ofcourse be reconfigured to adjust to a specific situation.
Hope this helps someone that is in the same situation.